# What book has a story about a man who goes to the moon and has a cyborg arm?

Tags: story-identification, cyborg, moon

I remember reading a book with a title which seemed like it was from the 80s or 90s like "Steel Justice" or "Metal Justice." If my memory's still right, the cover of the book is blue and probably shows a cyborg hand or arm.

Within the story, the main character gets attacked by a cyborg and has his arm upgraded. Because of the upgrade, it can act on its own and he'll automatically block bullets.

I do remember an ending scene where he defeats his nemesis (the same person who caused his injury) with electricity.

Can anyone help me remember the name of the book?